# Is it possible to show scheduled meetings in an Outlook calendar?

Tags: drupal, activities, calendar

I am working with an organisation that would like to show scheduled meetings and other activities in an MS Outlook calendar.  The activities should show as calendar items in the calendar of the staff member who added them.  So if a member of staff organises a meeting with a client this will appear in their calendar.

Is this possible?

They are using CiviCRM 4.6 on Drupal 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Administer -> Customize Data and Screens -> Display Preferences you can enable "Include ICal Invite to Activity Assignees". That add an ICal Invite to the meetings and other activities and they can then be accepted and placed in the Calendar.

Comment: Does this only work if you assign the activity to someone else?  They would like to be able to see all of their upcoming activities/meetings in Outlook (even those that they have created for themselves).

Comment: No, there are 3 fields in activites: added by, assigned to, and with contact. If you create an activity then "Added by" will contain your contact record. but you can also assign to yourself. Then you will get an email with the iCal too.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, for each activity that they want to appear in their calendar they would need to assign that activity to themselves.  They would then receive an email with an iCal attachment which they would have to accept in Outlook.  This sounds a bit clunky but I will give it a go.  Thanks.

Comment: yeah, this is also an option to try: https://civicrm.org/extensions/civicrm-activities-icalendar-feed